# Connectivity issues stuck long period of time between MongoDB and Prisma

Tags: mongodb, prisma

```
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": MongoDB database "udemy-clone" at "cluster0.ds3t9sn.mongodb.net"
Error: MongoDB error
Kind: An error occurred during DNS resolution: proto error: io error: 通訊端操作嘗試連線到一個無法連線的網路。 (os error 10051), labels: {}
0: schema_core::commands::schema_push::Calculate `from`
         at schema-engine\core\src\commands\schema_push.rs:29
1: schema_core::state::SchemaPush
         at schema-engine\core\src\state.rs:436
```

I checked clearly that I had allowed access from anywhere for the IP address on my MongoDB cluster and even how I tried to connect the MongoDB Atlas with Prisma it still occurred the above issue. Can anyone figure out what is the major problem that the connectivity has error?